# filtering using awk split

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file of the following format

```
build:chr:pos sample_1 sample_2 ...
38:1:189665   1        1
38:1:416546   0        0        ...
38:1:9000     0        1        ...
...           ...      ...      ...
```

I am attempting to filter it based on the pos of each item held in the first column. My thought process is that using awk's `split` I can grab the substring containing pos and filter it based on a given threshold. This is my awk statement currently

```
awk -v upper_bound=100000 -v lower_bound=100 
'{
   split($1,a,":");
   if (a[3] < upper_bound && a[3] >= lower_bound) 
      print $0
}'
```

and currently it is producing empty output. It should print out all those items with pos between 100-100000. I believe the problem is within my conditional statement as when its removed, it successfully prints. Could anyone advise as to whats wrong?

Edit: posted a bad example, i do indeed have items that should pass the filtering but are not.

Comment: The values of `189665` and `416546` are greater than `upper_bound` in your example, no? Do you have an example with example output?

Comment: Your `awk` works if you make `upper_bound=1000000` (ie, bigger than the values in the example)

Comment: Could you please do lemme know if my code helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler awk command using multiple delimiters (space and colon):

```
awk -F"[: ]" -v lower_bound=100 -v upper_bound=100000 'lower_bound<=$3 && $3<=upper_bound' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

As dwag mentioned already in his comments that your shown samples are NOT having any line which is satisfying your conditions so thus you are NOT seeing anything in output. I have also fixed 2 things(1st: `'{` place for `awk` first block and 2nd: `{`} added for `if` condition for safer side).

I have also tested your code(after applying small changes mentioned above) with 1 more line too as follow, let's say following is Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
build:chr:pos sample_1 sample_2 ...
38:1:189665   1        1
38:1:416546   0        0        ...
39:1:9999     1        2        ...
...           ...      ...      ...
```

Now when I run following code it gives as follows output:

```
awk -v upper_bound=100000 -v lower_bound=100 '{
   split($1,a,":");
   if (a[3] < upper_bound && a[3] >= lower_bound){
      print $0}
}'  file82836752
39:1:9999     1        2        ...
```

***EDIT:*** 1 more thought, check `cat -v Input_file` for your Input_file if in case it has CONTROL M characters if yes then try to remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` too. Just an another thought if this could be an issue too.